# Get Values into Gruntfile from OS X Keychain

Tags: macos, gruntjs, keychain

In a Gruntfile, it's possible to load values from a JSON file using `grunt.file.readJSON(...)`.  Is there a module, plugin, etc., that allows loading values from the OS X keychain?

I'm looking for a more secure way to store, e.g., AWS credentials for use with Grunt than just some random JSON file that happens not to be committed to my git repo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the best way, but I stumbled into using [the `keytar` node module](http://atom.github.io/node-keytar/).  I added

```js
var keytar = require('keytar');
```

toward the top of my `module.exports` function in my Gruntfile, got the values of the properties I wanted read from the keychain like

```js
aws: {
    key: keytar.getPassword('AWS-S3-AccessKeyId', 'example.com'),
    secret: keytar.getPassword('AWS-S3-SecretAccessKey', 'example.com')
},
```

inside the `grunt.initConfig({...})` call, and used the `node` REPL to set the values:

```js
keytar = require('keytar');
keytar.addPassword('AWS-S3-AccessKeyId', 'example.com', 'AccessKeyGoesHere')
keytar.addPassword('AWS-S3-SecretAccessKey', 'example.com', 'SuperSecretKeyHere')
```